# How to count the number of characters after the last comma

Tags: php, strlen

I have a string similar to the following and would like to count the number of the characters after the last comma.

```
$test = "apple, orange, green, red";
$count = strlen($test);
echo "$count";
```

and it should return 3.
I have used the strlen command but it returns the length of the whole string.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: `$count = strlen(end(explode(', ', $test)));`

Comment: @alex review it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$splitString = explode(',', $test);
echo strlen($splitString[count($splitString)-1]); //it will show length of characters of last part
```

Comment: This returns 4 not 3, as the OP requested.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can use from following codes:

```
$test = "apple, orange, green, red";
$ex = explode(',',$test);
$ex = array_reverse($ex);
echo strlen(trim($ex[0]));
```

first convert your String to an array and reverse that and get length of 0 index.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$test = "apple, orange, green, red";
// Exploded string with ,(comman) and store as an array
$explodedString = explode(",", $test);
// with end() get last element
$objLast = end($explodedString);
// remove white space before and after string
$tempStr = trim($objLast);
//With strlen() get count of number of characters in string
$finalStringLen = strlen($tempStr);
print_r("Length of '".$tempStr."' is ".$finalStringLen);
?>
```

Comment: This returns 4, not 3 as the OP requested

Comment: @bumperbox i forget to trim and I did it

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to explode the string with the comma(,) then store it into any variable. You have to pass the variable that you have used previously for storing exploded array value in END function because END function required any variable as a parameter. If you use END function and do something inside rather than passing the parameter you will get an error. After you have to trim value which is return from END function for removing useless space then after use strlen function for getting the exact count of last String.

```
$test = "apple, orange, green, red";

$t = explode(",",$test);

print_r(strlen(trim(end($t))));
```